# Can't get "col" background color to cover the entire area without a scrollbar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying create a simple page layout using Bootstrap 3.3.7

I have a scrollable sidebar on the left and a simple element on the right a simple element like an image.

I would like to add a background image and color on the right side that covers the entire column without having a scrollbar because it is really not needed as I onnly have 1 simple and small element there.

[image]

However, a scrollbar appears and when you scroll down, the sidebar remains fixed but an empty white space appears at the top of it.

[image]

If I can get the background color to cover the right area without the scrollbar, I think the sidebar would fix it self as there is no need for an overall scrollbar.

I tried `overflow: hidden` but that didn't do anything.

I am using default bootstrap elements

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" style="background: purple;">

            <div class="row placeholders" style="text-align: center;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
html, body, .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 52px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: block;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
        background-color: #273646;
    }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
    margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
    padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .main {
        padding-right: 40px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
}
.main .page-header {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/halnex/3qkgyn0w/5/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this:

```
.container-fluid {
  height: auto;
  }
```

and

```
 body {
  background: purple; 
}
```

(`.container-fluid` has `height: 100%` otherwise, which is added to the navbar height, which again results in an overall height of more than 100%, hence the scrollbar.)

https://jsfiddle.net/2nn39oqm/

Comment: Thanks man, this fixed the scrollbar issue. But what about the background color covering the entire right column?

Comment: If I added "height: 100vh;" on the right column, the scrollbar reappears and I have the same problem as before.

Comment: Put the background into the body CSS - I changed my answer and the fiddle